# EntityDataSource Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, entitydatasource

This is a little painful, I feel like this should be really easy.

I have a EntityDataSource as such:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="TaskDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ScheduleEntities" DefaultContainerName="ScheduleEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="TaskItems" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" OrderBy="it.Duration" Where="it.deleted = False">
```

And I can't for the life of me get it to show me only the not deleted results. The OrderBy works and everything is fine...I just can't get it to filter.

Comment: Is this verbatim? `it.deleted` might need to be `it.Deleted`

Comment: Verbatim. The column in the database is "deleted" and I have tried both.

Comment: Change `False` to `FALSE` and see how that goes.

Comment: No dice, that didn't work either, with "Deleted" or "deleted"

Answer (score 0):

you need to make AutoGenerateWhereClause property to true in the EntityDataSource,

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="TaskDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ScheduleEntities" DefaultContainerName="ScheduleEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="TaskItems" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" OrderBy="it.Duration" Where="it.deleted = False" AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
```

Comment: And you can filter as you like on QueryCreated event of the entity datasource

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by making a linqDataSource with a filter made in the UI and took the filter format, here is the code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="TaskDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ScheduleEntities" DefaultContainerName="ScheduleEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="TaskItems" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" OrderBy="" Where="deleted == @deleted">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="False" Name="deleted" Type="Boolean" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

BUT, I couldn't end up using this because I needed to use the dynamic filters on the grid also, so my workaround was to hide rows during the binding process(if there is a more efficient way please update me!) with this:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var editItem = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem && !e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        bool success,deleted;
        bool.TryParse(item["deleted"].Text, out success);
        if (success)
        {
            deleted = bool.Parse(item["deleted"].Text);
            if (deleted)
            {
                item.Display = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```